# Raycast не проходит через UI элементы

Tags: c#, unity3d

Использую код :

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = PlayerCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
   //...
}
```

Но заметил, что луч не проходить сквозь UI элементы. Как сделать, что бы он проходил через них? В интернете не нашел нормальной информации. Нашел какой-то Graphic Raycast, но ничего не понял. Help me

Comment: Так ведь `PlayerCam.ScreenPointToRay` не имеет ничего общего с регистрацией прохождения луча через объекты... Чтобы хоть что-то регистрировать (видимо, объекты) - вам нужен `Physics.Raycast`.

Comment: Что-то я не понял вообще ничего.

Comment: `Camera.ScreenPointToRay` возвращает просто луч `Ray`, он имеет бесконечную длину и направление, он не должен ни через что проходить и никакие проверки через него не сделаешь.

Comment: Но у меня вместо UI элемента регистрируется обьект, в который попал луч (в моем случае - terrain).

Comment: Добавьте **полный** самодостаточный пример в вопрос.

Comment: Ну вот вы добавили подробности уже после того, как я начал уточнять - будьте добры сразу добавлять **всю** информацию в вопросю

Comment: Так что делать-то? Я так и не понял :D

Comment: Сейчас оформлю ответ, не гоните лошадей :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я понимаю UI элементы не являются элементами физики, поэтому `Physics.Raycast`вам не поможет [(документация)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Raycasters.html). Вот `GraphicRaycaster`как раз то, что вам нужно. Этот элемент находится на `Canvas`и позволяет рейкастить элементы интерфейса, при этом можно также использовать фильтрацию по слоям. У себя в проекте вешал на `Canvas` даже два `GraphicRaycaster`, чтобы отличать разные элементы интерфейса находящиеся в разных слоях.

Comment: Хм, действительно правильный ответ, ошибся.